# Right header's width

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry for the stupid question, but i don't understand what is the right `header` width

[image]

```
width: 100%;
padding-left: 32px;
padding-right: 32px;
```

or

```
width: 1216px;
max-width: 100%
```

?

Comment: `width: 1216px;` is a fix width as u declare while `width: 100%;` is according to the size of the screen **or**  size of the parent DOM that the element being child to (responsive ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
width: 1216px;
```

means you have an element with the exact width of 1216px as seen the in picture

```css
width: 100%;
```

means that the element width now equals to the width of the container element minus `margin` and `padding` if specified.